# Building Quickfix on Windows for 64bit

Tags: c++, windows, quickfix

I've downloaded what I believe is the latest Quickfix from [Github](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix). It builds fine as an x86 project, but when I try to build it as an x64 project there's a load of warnings (see below).

I can't imagine I'm the first person to want to build a 64bit version of Quickfix. A lot of the warnings look like they're Windows specific (eg casting the `SOCKET` to `int`).

Is there a version of Quickfix out there that builds cleanly as a 64bit library on Windows, or will I need to go in and patch it myself?

> FieldMap.cpp(205): warning C4267: '+=': conversion from 'size_t' to
>   'int', possible loss of data FileStore.cpp(135): warning C4477:
>   'fscanf_s' : format string '%lu' requires an argument of type
>   'unsigned long *', but variadic argument 3 has type 'size_t *'
>   FileStore.cpp(135): note: consider using '%zu' in the format string
>   FileStore.cpp(197): warning C4477: 'fprintf' : format string '%lu'
>   requires an argument of type 'unsigned long', but variadic argument 3
>   has type '::size_t' FileStore.cpp(197): note: consider using '%zu' in
>   the format string
>   c:\apps\VS2017Pro\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\utility(239):
>   warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss
>   of data FileStore.cpp(136): note: see reference to function template
>   instantiation 'std::pair &std::pair::operator
>   =(std::pair &&)' being compiled FileStore.cpp(136): note: see reference to function template
>   instantiation 'std::pair &std::pair::operator
>   =(std::pair &&)' being compiled SocketConnection.cpp(89): warning C4267: '+=': conversion
>   from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
>   SocketMonitor.cpp(141): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double'
>   to 'long', possible loss of data SocketMonitor.cpp(146): warning
>   C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'long', possible loss of data
>   SocketMonitor.cpp(232): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from
>   'SOCKET' to 'int', possible loss of data SocketMonitor.cpp(271):
>   warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'SOCKET' to 'int',
>   possible loss of data SocketMonitor.cpp(312): warning C4244:
>   'initializing': conversion from 'SOCKET' to 'int', possible loss of
>   data Utility.cpp(105): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from
>   'SOCKET' to 'int', possible loss of data Utility.cpp(128): warning
>   C4244: 'return': conversion from 'SOCKET' to 'int', possible loss of
>   data Utility.cpp(139): warning C4996: 'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or
>   InetPton() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to
>   disable deprecated API warnings C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.1\Include\um\Winsock2.h(1850): note: see declaration of
>   'inet_addr' Utility.cpp(150): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from
>   'SOCKET' to 'int', possible loss of data Utility.cpp(155): warning
>   C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of
>   data Utility.cpp(276): warning C4309: '=': truncation of constant
>   value Utility.cpp(299): warning C4996: 'inet_ntoa': Use inet_ntop() or
>   InetNtop() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to
>   disable deprecated API warnings C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.1\Include\um\Winsock2.h(1868): note: see declaration of
>   'inet_ntoa' Utility.cpp(314): warning C4996: 'inet_addr': Use
>   inet_pton() or InetPton() instead or define
>   _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\Winsock2.h(1850):
>   note: see declaration of 'inet_addr' Utility.cpp(322): warning C4996:
>   'gethostbyname': Use getaddrinfo() or GetAddrInfoW() instead or define
>   _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\Winsock2.h(2238):
>   note: see declaration of 'gethostbyname' Utility.cpp(328): warning
>   C4996: 'inet_ntoa': Use inet_ntop() or InetNtop() instead or define
>   _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\Winsock2.h(1868):
>   note: see declaration of 'inet_ntoa' Utility.cpp(337): warning C4996:
>   'inet_ntoa': Use inet_ntop() or InetNtop() instead or define
>   _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\Winsock2.h(1868):
>   note: see declaration of 'inet_ntoa' Utility.cpp(399): warning C4244:
>   '=': conversion from 'uintptr_t' to 'FIX::thread_id', possible loss of
>   data Utility.cpp(418): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from
>   'FIX::thread_id' to 'void *' of greater size Utility.cpp(419): warning
>   C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'FIX::thread_id' to 'HANDLE' of
>   greater size Utility.cpp(428): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion
>   from 'FIX::thread_id' to 'HANDLE' of greater size Utility.cpp(438):
>   warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'HANDLE' to
>   'unsigned int' Utility.cpp(438): warning C4302: 'type cast':
>   truncation from 'HANDLE' to 'unsigned int'

df

Comment: I couldn't find much. Can I have a copy when you're done? :-)

Comment: Which compiler are you using on Win 64? Visual Studio? I build 64bit QuickFix version 1.2 for FIX version 4.2 (mostly but also the others) on Windows 64 all the time. My compile just now produces one warning about the size_t to int conversion but not the list you have above. My compiler settings for Visual Studio 2013 are : -DNOMINMAX -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DYY_NO_UNISTD_H /EHsc . Some of these may be irrelevant to QuickFix.

Comment: I'm using VS2017. For example, there are errors about the socket return type.

Comment: Have you tried preprocessor definitions : _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS ? Also make sure the preprocessor value WIN32  is set. WIN32 does not mean 32bit in this case, it's a commonly used platform switch for Windows desktop and server versions.

Comment: ... also the stdafx.h file included with QuickFix C++ defines preprocessor variable WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN which disables winsock includes from windows.h , this may fix the socket warnings at least.

Comment: @JimmyNJ - the compiler warnings are caused by a socket handle being 64bits wide on Win64. QuickFix uses an int to store it, which is only 32bits wide.